# Как создать в триггере несколько условий?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как создать в триггере несколько условий ?

Есть триггер, как задать для него несколько условий выполнения действий для  каждого столбца?

**Допустим если мы обновляем**:

**url_avator** - то вызывается UPDATE  friends_table  SET  ava.......

**url_avator2** - то вызывается UPDATE  friends_table2  SET  ava.......

```
BEGIN
SET foreign_key_checks =  0 ;
 UPDATE  friends_table  SET  avatar=NEW.avatar  WHERE  avatar=OLD.avatar;
 UPDATE  friends_table2  SET  avatar2=NEW.avatar2  WHERE  avatar2=OLD.avatar2;
SET foreign_key_checks =  1 ;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BEGIN
SET foreign_key_checks =  0 ;
IF (NEW.url_avator<>OLD.url_avator) THEN
    UPDATE  friends_table  SET  avatar=NEW.avatar  WHERE  avatar=OLD.avatar;
END IF;
IF (NEW.url_avator2<>OLD.url_avator2) THEN
    UPDATE  friends_table2  SET  avatar2=NEW.avatar2  WHERE  avatar2=OLD.avatar2;
END IF;
SET foreign_key_checks =  1 ;
END
```

Comment: В вопросе не сказано, что `url_avator` и `url_avator2` не могут обновляться одновременно. Поэтому, наверно, логичнее вместо `... ELSE IF ...` написать `... END IF; IF ...`?

Comment: @Yaant, логично... спасибо. Исправлено